Identifying Application Information and MAC Addresses Using IPFIX Data
I'm working on a network monitoring project where we're leveraging IPFIX data to understand the nature of the traffic flowing through our network. Specifically, I'm interested in two key pieces of information:
Application Identification:
We need to identify the application-layer protocols or services (like HTTP, HTTPS, DNS, etc.) associated with each flow. I'm aware that IPFIX can include an applicationId, but I'm looking for more details on how this ID is typically used or interpreted. Are there specific standards or mappings that I should be aware of? How can I ensure accurate identification of applications, especially for web services or cloud-based applications?Additionally, how should we handle cases where the applicationId might be missing or not provided by the exporter?
MAC Address Information:
Additionally, I'm interested in capturing MAC addresses associated with these flows. I know that certain Information Elements (IEs) like sourceMacAddress and postDestinationMacAddress might be available, but I'm curious about the best practices for extracting and using this data. Are these elements commonly supported, and how can I set this up in a typical IPFIX exporter and collector setup?
Thanks in Advance!

The router strips off the layer-2 frame, losing any layer-2 addressing, such as MAC addresses. Application identification is a very complex subject, and it is not an eact science. Even up-to-date Next-Gen firewall can get it wrong. Often, it is a best guess.

So Wt would be the alternatives for achieving my goal??

Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Traditionally, the application is identified by the L4 source/destination port. That isn't usually done on the IPFIX exporter but further up in the workflow.
There may be an applicationId field, but how that is determined - by L4 port, fingerprinting, deep packet inspection, ... - isn't defined by IPFIX standards. The field itself is defined in RFC 6759.
Data link layer (L2) information is not commonly included in IPFIX data. There's a draft RFC 7133. You'd need to check which options your gear supports.
